# Android Studio Current NDK support is deprecated

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to implement [OsmAnd](https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand) open source project from github to my computer. All works fine but when I press `run` I got this error

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:OsmAnd:assembleFreeLegacyArmv5Debug]
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
Validating translations
:OsmAnd:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:compileFreeLegacyArmv5DebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:checkFreeLegacyArmv5DebugManifest
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:classes UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:androidJar UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileLint
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:checkReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:prepareReleaseDependencies
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileLint
:eclipse-compile:cardview:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:checkReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:cardview:prepareReleaseDependencies
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileLint
:eclipse-compile:design:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:checkReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:design:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:prepareOsmandEclipseCompileAppcompatUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:prepareReleaseDependencies
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex100Library UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareOsmandEclipseCompileAppcompatUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareOsmandEclipseCompileCardviewUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareOsmandEclipseCompileDesignUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:prepareFreeLegacyArmv5DebugDependencies
:OsmAnd:processFreeLegacyArmv5DebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectFreeLegacyArmv5DebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:buildOsmAndCore
"Not supported"
:OsmAnd:cleanupDuplicatesInCore
:OsmAnd:collectFonts UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectHelpContentsAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectHelpContentsStyle UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectMiscResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectRegionsInfoResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectRenderingStylesResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectRoutingResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectVoiceAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:copyStyleIcons UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:updateNoTranslate
:OsmAnd:validateTranslate UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:collectExternalResources
:OsmAnd:compileFreeLegacyArmv5DebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:compileFreeLegacyArmv5DebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:mergeFreeLegacyArmv5DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:mergeFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:processFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:compileFreeLegacyArmv5DebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:packageAllFreeLegacyArmv5DebugClassesForMultiDex UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:shrinkFreeLegacyArmv5DebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:createFreeLegacyArmv5DebugMainDexClassList UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:dexFreeLegacyArmv5Debug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:542)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
    ... 12 more
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(bsh.CollectionManager$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(bsh.Interpreter$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(bsh.SimpleNode$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
    ... 12 more
2 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':OsmAnd:dexFreeLegacyArmv5Debug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 19.597 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I'm trying to solve this problem almost 6 hours, but still no progress. After lot of research I found [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openstreetmap.osmand/5649) post, but that does not solved my problem. Is it possible to get rid of this error?

Comment: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000) means that the dex parser building your project found a class file that was built with a different version of Java than what it is running on. I am guessing you have tried a clean then build, and also deleting your build target directory's contents? Are you including any pre-built libraries as dependencies?

Comment: @mbarnes thank you for your comment, yes I'm including pre-build libraries. I thought that problem is with android-ndk?

Comment: The dx tool is a part of the ndk toolchain. It turns class files into executables for Dalvik. Somewhere in your dependencies or source you are including pre-built libraries that were created with an incompatible compiler. There are a number of different solutions. Try this blog post's answer and excellent description, but you are going to want java 1.7 not 1.6 (0034.0000 not 0033.0000) http://www.alonsoruibal.com/my-gradle-tips-and-tricks/